# Is there a way of adding an HTML when the extension's icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

In fact,

I want to write a little chrome extension that gives me the dimension of the window.

So I decided to use a HTML code injected into the webpage when I click on the extension's icon

I tried many things but it doesn't work (the html injected does not appear)

This is my `manifest.json` for now:

```
{
    "name": "Dimension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Giving you the window dimensions live!",

    "permissions": [
      "tabs", "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "css": ["dimension.css"],
        "js": ["inject.js"]
      }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["dimension.html", "dimension.css", "dimension.js"],
    "browser_action": {},
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

`inject.js` file:

```
console.log("inject script loaded")

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(inject)

function inject() {
    var iFrame  = document.createElement ("iframe");
    iFrame.src  = chrome.extension.getURL ("dimension.html");

    document.body.insertBefore (iFrame, document.body.firstChild);
    console.log('html injected')
}
```

I also tried `inject.js` as the background script but it was opening the html file into the Extension Background environment (when you inspect the background script)

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in devtools to inspect and debug your code. It should show an error about chrome.browserAction being undefined. This API can't be used in a content script: you need a background script for most extension API listeners.

To access the web page you need a content script but there's no need to declare it, simply use the [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#functionality), and there's also no need for those permissions. A single [`activeTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) is sufficient in this scenario.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Dimension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Giving you the window dimensions live!",
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["dimension.*"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {},
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'inject.js'});
});
```

In your inject.js file replace chrome.browserAction line with `inject();`